# What does 2>&1 (usually after 1>/dev/null) variable in shell scripting do?

Tags: shell, scripting, io-redirection

I'm currently learning shell scripting, and I am trying to understand a source code i got from GitHub that contains the line:

```
mountpoint /mnt/share 1>/dev/null 2>&1
```

What is the 2>&1 variable hold?
What is its purpose?

I tried Google Search but they block punctuation...

Can someone give me some directions? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2>&1 redirects the standard error to the standard output
Official documentation:https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html

Comment: After i execute this command, do you know why does the output of $? returns value 0 if mount exists and 1 if value doesnt exists? I read the documentation but couldnt understand the logic.

Comment: With 1> you only redirect the stdout and with 2> the stderr, $? shows the return value of the last command, in your case mountpoint, so you have to read its documentation https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/mountpoint.1.html

Comment: I saw it! The EXIT STATUS section... So all Linux commands must have this EXIT STATUS code then. Didnt know that... Thanks! Have a nice day.

Comment: Exactly, linux command are normal programs so they have an exit status(the return value), you have to think at it as the last return in the program, if you're familiar with C/C++(most popular commands are written with these) it's the return value of the function main(), in more advanced language like Python this is hidden. Have a nice day!

Comment: @alexHX12 "higher level" is not at all the same as "more advanced"